# Scale array according to pre-specified sum

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math

I want to take an existing array and scale it accordingly so that the final array sum is a specific (user input) number. For example:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.random.randint(5, size=(2, 2))
sum   = np.sum(array)
print(array)
maxsum = 5

array = np.round((array*maxsum)/sum)

print(np.sum(array))
print(array)
```

Using the above code for an array such as: `[[1 4] [4 3]]` returns `[[0. 2.] [2. 1.]]`, which is fine as it sums up to the sum I want according to each elements "importance".

The problem starts when I want to scale bigger arrays such as 60x60 or larger because each elements is normalized in range [0,1] so every element is very close to 0 after it is divided by a large number (sum), thus every final element is returned as 0.

I need to output to be integers and always positive.

I've tried using ceil or floor instead of round and normalizing according to the maximum value of the initial array but I still cant find a solution. Any tip would be helpful, thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you use `np.round`? do you need your output elements to be integers too? if so, you cannot necessarily linearly scale ints into ints s.t. the sum is a certain value. You can do approximation and toggle ceil/floor to achieve that.

Comment: @Ehsan Yes, I need to output to be integers, sorry I didn't mention it.

Comment: Can't you wrap the contents around an exponential function? And just logarithm-out of it? 

ex: `np.exp(0.4) / sum` will be much more reasonable than purely `0.4/sum`

And then when you want the actual value, you can just use natural log to "exit" out the effect of the exp function

Comment: @progenRobot this returns some negative values, I want to have only positive integers in the solutions